# What type of Sage Mode does Hashirama enter?

Tags: naruto

We all know that the following people are capable of entering Sage Mode:

- Naruto
- Jiraiya
- Orochimaru (learnt but couldn't use because of his body, or rather his vessels)
- Kabuto
- Hashirama

*Naruto and Jiraiya* learnt it from the Toads (at *Mount Myōboku*), hence they go into the **Toad-style Sage Mode**. *Orochimaru and Kabuto* learnt it from the Snakes (at *Ryūchi Cave*), hence they go into the **Snake-style Sage Mode**. But what type of Sage Mode does Hashirama enter? I read a lot about the Sage Mode and Senjutsu, but couldn't find any info about Hashirama's Sage Mode.

Comment: While reading the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Mode), *"The method of learning the other styles of Sage Mode are **unknown**, as the only one shown was the toad's style."*.

Comment: Chances are it is related to his summon

Comment: I think he learned it naturally since he can use Wood Style. Any thoughts?

Comment: One logical choice is that it comes from Slugs, since that species is the only one left of the trio. Moreover, his granddaughter has a Summoning contract with slugs.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. Like how his counterpart Madara was the first to awaken the Mangekyo Sharingan (at least in "our" times), then awaken it further into a Rinnegan. It is suitable for Hashirama to also have done awesome things which no one knew of before.

Comment: @Happy, good thought about the Slugs, however nothing in manga nor in anime showed Hashirama uses summoning Slug. My theory is that since he inherit the body of the Sage of Sixth path, maybe it comes naturally and Hashirama learn it eventually.=)

Comment: The good news is that with Obito now being either defeated or "won over" by Naruto's speech, Hashirama v/s Madara is likely to come up pretty soon, and there is a very good chance his sage mode would be explained at the time.

Comment: @R.J., I think turn into "wood" not "stone".. LOL.

Comment: @NaraShikamaru Well, yeah, that's why I didn't post it as an answer, but Kishimoto likes to use "themes" from mythology and legends (like Amaterasu, Tsukuyomi, Susanoo, Izanagi, Izanami), and there's also a legend about "Snake, Slugs and Toads", so for completeness, he is might have planned for a Slug Sage Mode. Right now, there is no other character with whom he can display it. (unless Sakura learned Sage Mode during the timeskip. :P)

Comment: Yeah, you might have to wait for the answer, but you certainly don't need to wait for an upvote. :)
What's wrong with the site these days? Why are people so reluctant to vote? :(

Comment: Pure speculation here: I believe it is the snail type sage mode (which wasn't revealed, but is highly likely to exist), since the family connection to Tsunade, who uses snails (or rather, snail). Again, pure speculation.

Comment: FWIW , take a yonder at this thread. The original thread was on NF, but this guy took the theory and expanded it even more. http://narutobase.net/forums/showthread.php?t=331340

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I deliver my answer, we must ask ourselves what **Sage Mode** is.

### What is Sage Mode?

From [Sage Mode article](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Mode):

> Sage Mode is the **empowered** state humans enter when they **learn to draw** natural energy inside them and blending it with their chakra. By doing so, the human creates **new senjutsu chakra** that allows them to enter Sage Mode.

The next question is: Where do shinobi learn it from?

> Thus far, Sage Mode has been shown to be **taught** in two places: at Mount Myōboku by the toads, and Ryūchi Cave by the snakes.

The articles clearly states that Sage Mode is achieved when the user **learns** to draw natural energy and mixes it with their chakra, **and** Mount Myoboku and Ryuchi Cave are two known places where they can **learn to do so**.

Now, the requirements for learning Sage Mode:

> According to Fukasaku, only those who already possess "**extreme chakra levels**" can utilise natural energy to **invoke** senjutsu.

### Hashirama Senju's Sage Mode

Let us move onto [Hashirama Senju](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hashirama_Senju).

> Because of his large chakra reserves, Hashirama is able to use senjutsu by entering Sage Mode, a feat he could perform instantaneously; it is not known where he learned it.

If we look at his [abilities section](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hashirama_Senju#Abilities):

> He is similarly knowledgeable of skills he has no training in, being able to recognize the Samsara of Heavenly Life Technique.

Taking into consideration the aforementioned details, **in conclusion**, it is *possible* that Hashirama learned Sage Mode by himself. Since it is self-taught, it is not animal-influenced. Hence it would be something-like a "Normal-Without-Animal-Influence-Sage-Mode".

### What led me to this conclusion?

> Learning Sage Mode at Mount Myōboku or Ryūchi Cave grants the user with a **toad** and **snake-influenced** Sage Mode respectively,

That is the explanation for the toad/snake techniques used by Jiraiya/Naruto and Orochimaru/Kabuto.

However, Hashirama's Sage Mode hasn't shown what animal-influence it possesses so far. Therefore, he couldn't have learned his Sage Mode from Mount Myōboku or Ryūchi Cave.

---

His **Sage Mode** strengthens his Wood-Release techniques and his overall performance drastically.

From Naruto manga, Chapter 657, Page 08:

[image: Madara]

Madara-sama's line: "**Only this much power... This will be easy to handle.**", shows that an experienced and powerful [shinobi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha) can use Senjutsu within mere moments.

### Wrapping up

Since there is no official details about what Sage Mode Hashirama uses, my conclusion is classified as a possibility.

Another possible conclusion is detailed in this answer: [Is there a slug based Sage Mode?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11736/sage-mode-for-slugs/11746#11746)

Answer (score 0):

I Think Hashirama enters into "Bull Sage Mode", as the Bull Sage was one of the original 5 Sages which were

1. The Eagle-Owl Sage,
2. The Scorpion Sage,
3. The Bull Sage,
4. The Salamander Sage
5. The Toad Sage

And it happens the Bull Sage specialises at Wood release which was Hashirama's specialty

Comment: Interesting! Where did you get this information from? Can you provide a cite link?

Comment: this is invalid as kabuto and orochimaru has dragon/snake sage power.

Comment: Don't forget the slug powers

Comment: This is fan fiction: http://narutofanon.wikia.com/wiki/The_Five_Great_Sages_of_The_Ninja_World

Answer (score -1):

Hashirama Senju has the Forest Sage Mode. It says in the wikia, that his Sage Mode is a special type that only he can use. Thats fitting since he would need the Forest Style to increase the effect of his Wood Style.

Comment: ever heard about shikkotsu woods it is the place where hashirama learnt his wood style.

Comment: more then forest i think it is **Wood** type as he is the only person to know wood release technique and in his sage form he makes the wood seal as explained by yamato.