# Is there a slug based Sage Mode?

Tags: naruto

As we know, Naruto (Jiraiya's apprentice) has mastered the Sage Mode of toads. Also, Kabuto (Orochimaru's apprentice) has mastered the Sage Mode of snakes. So, my question is, is there a Sage Mode of slugs (related to Tsunade)?

Comment: It is possible and somewhat likely. It has not been ruled out anywhere, but it hasn't been mentioned anywhere either.

Comment: Answers can be merely speculation but I do have a theory.

Comment: Lady tsunades diamond seal on her forehead has nothing to do with sage mode it is a completely different jutsu that stores her chakra yes it does appear that Hashirama is in sage mode in this picture but it does not look anything like tsuandes jutsu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Sage Mode of the slugs is *somewhat related* to the Sage Mode of Hashirama Senju (First Hokage). He learnt Sage Mode in Shikkotsu Woods/Forest, a legendary place that is equally famous as Mount Myōboku (toad) and Ryūchi Cave (snake). It is the home of the slug Katsuyu, parts of which are summoned by Tsunade and one of her disciples, Sakura Haruno.

Evidence:

In Hashirama's fight with Madara, it appears that he enters a *Sage Mode* (bottom right corner) similar to Tsunade's, with a diamond shape tatoo-like symbol in her forehead.

[image]

Though it is not explicitly said neither in the manga nor in the anime that Tsunade enters Sage Mode, it is clear that Hashirama did.

Comment: I was thinking same.

Comment: @berserk, you can marked it as an answer if this satisfies your question.

Comment: `Hashirama Senju (First Hokage). He learnt Sage Mode in Shikkotsu Woods/Forest` can you provide details to support this?

Answer (score 0):

Sages use nature energy.  Tsunades "100 healings technique" uses her own stored chakra.

Also, Hashirama does not use the same healing technique.  His is called "Mitotic Regeneration" in his sage mode and it works by increasing the speed at which his cells replicate through mitosis which replaces the damaged or dead cells.

I'm too lazy to find the exact episode, I just watch/read a lot of Naruto..

Answer (score 0):

I think hashirama does use slug sage, and I think that his wife mito uzumaki tried to imitate him, but with out the risks that sage training has sense she os the nine tails jinjuriki, and developed an jutsu, seal (being and uzumaki which is a clan known for their seals) , to imitate what her husband learned and created the hundred healings jutsu. I also think this because madara stated that tsunade’s 100 healings jutsu was the same as hashirama’s, but he didn’t use the hundred healings like his wife, or else he would have had the mark, so you can say that these two jutsu are based around the same thing. Slug sage. I also think the 100 healings seal is on the fore heal and spreads all over when activated because Mito most likely tried to imitate the forehead circle as well. So you can basically say the 100 healings technique is an off brand slug sage.

Comment: Actually I think Tsunade created the ability

Answer (score -1):

I also assume that Hashirama used the Slugs-based Sage Mode. I noticed the name Shikkotsu Forest/Wood, "wood" is in the name of the jutsu Hashirama used - the Wood style. This observation makes me conclude that Hashirama is a Slug Sage. I also noticed that Hashirama got a healing jutsu which the slugs used. The jutsu was also inherited by his granddaughter (Tsunade-sama), who also passed the power to her apprentice (Sakura-chan).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? - I'm not following the wood -> slug jump

Comment: The jump in logic is from Shikkotsu Forest/Wood to Wood Style doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yeah it logic.and,most of the times logic solve's problem that are mystery.