# Naruto Discussion about Hashirama's sage mode

Tags: naruto

in [this answer to "Is there a slug based Sage Mode?"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/11746/1587) it says

> He learnt Sage Mode in Shikkotsu Woods/Forest, a legendary place that is equally famous as Mount Myōboku (toad) and Ryūchi Cave (snake).

I was wondering if someone could direct me to the manga panels/anime episodes where it was mentioned that Hashirama trained at Shikkotsu Forest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type of Sage Mode does Hashirama enter?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5780/what-type-of-sage-mode-does-hashirama-enter)